# Resumable Upload client to cloud using JS

Tags: javascript, resumablejs, resumable

I am trying to find a suitable JS library that can work for resumable upload. My requirement is very simple:
Lets say user starts uploading a single file of 100 mb, in between there occurs a interruption of Network failure, then on restoring internet, file should resume form same point itself without invoking any user click event.

I have tried multiple libraries:

1. "@mux/upchunk", (it restarts uploading from very beginning)
2. "gcs-browser-upload", (it stores checksums in local storage but doesn't resume uploading again after restoring internet)
3. "@uppy/aws-s3" (not working)

So I am wondering if someone have already been implemented it in JS to share with me or if someone can recommend any JS library which can fulfil my needs.
I am using plain JS. Here is the link of repo where i have implementations for all above packages. https://github.com/momarcs/gcs-upload